# Mahout K-Means: No input clusters found error

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I am running Mahout 0.9 version on the most recent version of Hadoop. In K-Means algorithm, I transform the input data into vectors as required.

I executed the following command, to run K-Means:

```
mahout kmeans -i /user/ubuntu/Test/Vec/tfidf-vectors/ -c /user/ubuntu/Test/init-cluster -o /user/ubuntu/Test/Result -x 10 -k 2 -ow -cl
```

`/user/ubuntu/Test/init-cluster` is an empty folder, because I have already provided the -k parameter.

Interestingly, according to the log information below, Mahout deletes the cluster folder (`/user/ubuntu/Test/init-cluster`):

```
15/11/27 17:13:31 INFO common.HadoopUtil: Deleting /user/ubuntu/Test/init-cluster
```

In the end, Mahout gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
No input clusters found in /user/ubuntu/Test/init-cluster/part-randomSeed. 
Check your -c argument
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution to this problem?